# What's the exact syntax to concat 2 constraints in Rhino Mocks framework?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, rhino, rhino-mocks-3.5

I see in the Rhino source code the following code:

```
// Summary:
//     Or operator for constraints
public static AbstractConstraint operator |(AbstractConstraint c1, AbstractConstraint c2);
```

But in practice, I can use either **|**  or  **||**.

Similarly, both **&** and **&&** work the same way.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a C# issue. You can't overload the conditional logical operators - `&&` and `||` directly, in order to overload them the programmer has to overload the `&`,`|`, `true` and `false` operators, and those operators are used to evaluate an expression containing the `&&` and `||` operators. More details in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691312%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Concerning Rhino Mocks, he chose to implement the `true` and `false` operators in a way that prevents [short circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and makes the `&&` and `||` operators equivalent to `&` and `|`, ILSpy output:

```cs
public static bool operator false(AbstractConstraint c)
{
    return false;
}

public static bool operator true(AbstractConstraint c)
{
    return false;
}
```